# Problem on passing array to ajax request in laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to pass array through ajax request

```
<input type="text" name="item_name[]">
<input type="text" name="address">

 $(document).on('click', '#save_info', function () {
        var address = $("#address").val();
        var item_name = $("[name^='item_name']");

       $.ajax({
            url: '/save_information',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                address: address,
                item_name: item_name,
          }
        });
    });
```

In my controller

```
    $item_name = $request->item_name;
    $array_count = count($item_name);
```

It makes error. How can i save array value using loop. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `$("[name^='item_name']").val()` instead of just `$("[name^='item_name']")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable item_name holds DOM Node instead of input values. You'd have to make it either `var item_name = $("[name^='item_name']").val()` or `var item_name = $("[name^='item_name']").value`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but still it says **count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable**

Comment: @MujahidurRahmanMithunIUB Do you have multiple inputs that match this `[name^='item_name']` selector ? If not, you can simply use `var item_name = [$("[name^='item_name']").val()];`

Comment: var item_name = [$("[name^='item_name']").val()]; I used this but it contains only one value. 1st value

Comment: @MujahidurRahmanMithunIUB That is why I've asked if you have multiple elements that match the selector because the solution will be different in that case, you'll have to use something like `var item_name = $("[name^='item_name']").map(function() { return $(this).val() }).get()`

Answer (score 1):

@Mujahidur Rahman Mithun IUB you can write this more shortly by using `serializeArray`.

```
    $(document).on('click', '#save_info', function () {
      var serializeData = $("[name^='item_name']").serializeArray();
      serializeData.push(
        {
          name: "address", value: $("#address").val()
        },
        {
          name: "_token", value: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
      );
      $.ajax({
        url: '/save_information',
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        data: serializeData
      });
    });
```

Or if you use `<form>`, then you can use with very few line code :

```
  $(document).on('click', '#save_info', function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/save_information',
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('form#myform').serialize(),
      });
    });
`
```